# image editing using opengl on user touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenGL ES 2.0 Vertex Transformation Algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777393/opengl-es-2-0-vertex-transformation-algorithms)

[image]how to create an app where image can be modified with user touch. I want create a plastic surgery li ke app where user can upload his/her image and edit to see that how they look like afetr surgery.i want to achieve this through opengl. being a newbie to both iphone programming and opengl im not able to start.please do provide me some initial ideas so that i can cn atleast start and try to achieve it.

[image]

Comment: erm.. this is not a simple task, and this place is for specific programming questions. however, I recommend this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial -- it helped me getting started with openGL on the iPhone (though I had done openGL programming on the PC before)

Comment: See also: [2D distortion of a face from an image on iOS? (similar to Fat Booth etc.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126067/2d-distortion-of-a-face-from-an-image-on-ios-similar-to-fat-booth-etc) among many, many others here.